# Android: reading Running + Paused State Tasks list

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want to read package name of all running applications.

Here is my Code to read Running applications:

```
public static getRunningTasks(final Context context) {
    final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (final RunningTaskInfo info : task) {
        System.out.println("base activity "+info.baseActivity.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

The output :

```
10-13 09:08:24.348: INFO/System.out(3295): base activity com.gt.mytest
10-13 09:08:24.348: INFO/System.out(3295): base activity com.android.launcher
```

But this is showing only the Application with [Running State in LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).

How can i read all(including Running State and Paused State) tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's wrong, That was my silly mistake

I used

```
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> service = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

instead of

```
List<RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

and got solution. :D